# How to store BigInteger in a H2/PSQL database using JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, h2

I'm trying to store a SHA256 hash as a numerical value, which seems like the optimal way to do it from a space and indexing POV. I'm using JPA with a simple field definition:

```
@NonNull
private BigInteger mybiginteger;
```

However, it refuses to insert the value.

I'm using a H2 database during unit tests, and now that I've added a BigInteger value in JPA it fails

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLDataException: Value too long for column "MYBIGINTEGER DECIMAL(19, 2)": "-12804752987762098394035772686106585063470084017442529046078187006797464553387.00 (79)"; SQL statement:
```

Skipping the test cases and trying it with Postgres it also fails with

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: numeric field overflow
  Detail: A field with precision 19, scale 2 must round to an absolute value less than 10^17.
```

JPA has created this as a numeric(19,2) field according to the DB tools. I can manually change the column definition and it works, but not how to set it to be portable between H2 and PSQL.

How can I correctly store BigInteger in a H2/PSQL database using JPA? 
Also, why is it allowing two decimal places for a BigInteger type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forced the column type with

```
@Column(precision = 100, scale = 0)
```

Precision 100 is probably way too high, but I'll calculate the correct value later.

Comment: You need about 78 digits precision. For Postgresql that's ca. 39 bytes + 3-8 bytes overhead (according to docs) =~ 45 bytes. A varchar(64) for a base64 encoded string would require 65 bytes. A bytea column 32+(1 to 4) or up to 36 bytes.

Comment: And again, I would argue as well with types and their intended usage. This communicates, "this is a number to calculate with". Do you want people to add, subtract, multiply, change sign of your hash? I doubt it. It's just a bunch of bytes.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by adding the following annotation on the property.

`@Column(columnDefinition = "BIGINT")`

Answer (score 0):

I would disagree that BigInteger is the right type for a Hash. Do you want to do arithmetic with your hash? I don't think so.

Java's `MessageDigest` for example, will give you a `byte[]` array with the hash. You can map a byte array efficiently as a binary/BLOB column.
Another portable way is to store it as a base64 encoded string.

```
@Lob
byte[] hash;
```

Assuming Postgresql, you can check the space requirements here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype.html

A 'bytea' column type would require up to 32 + 4 bytes. You can create indizes etc. on that column type.

Comment: I need to be able to query the hash. Can I do that efficiently with a byte[] in the DB? Or will it trigger full table searches? I also want to put a unique index on it, which I'm 99% convinced that it wouldn't work with a byte[]  / blob, but I might be wrong on this too.

Comment: Full table searches will always be triggered if there is no index, AFAIK. But my research has shown, that you can unique index bytea columns in Postgresql. Unfortunately, not explicitly mentioned in the docs, but I found something on a mailing list and this stack exchange QA: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/229677/definition-of-indexing-datatype-configuration-and-dbms-for-sha3-256-hashes/229678#229678